# cellForRowAtIndexPath: gets called but nothing shows up in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have an ordinary tableview with custom cells, working perfectly on iOS 6.0 but after upgrading the app to iOS 10, scattered problem arises.

Note: The app works as expected on iPhone 5, both on simulator and on a real device. All devices are running iOS 10.2 but iPhone 6 and above has the issues described below.

Some tableviews work fine just like before, while one of the tableViews always shows exactly 1 cell (even tough cellForRowAtIndexPath is called 7 times) and another table shows no cells at all despite `cellForRowAtIndexPath` getting called twice.

**I am wondering why the method is called if the tableview does not care to display the result?**

I am at a total loss as to what is going on and how to fix it. Been at it for a day with no progress at all. I have tried cleaning and running different builds and can not get the affected tableviews to behave correctly. I don't know what to try next? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Ok since you need some code here is a part of it that is not that sensitive. DataSource:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NOSUserInfo2 *userInfo = [S24SharedUserHandler currentUser];

    dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userInfo children]];

    if([userInfo student] || [userInfo teacher])
    {
        [dataSource insertObject:userInfo atIndex:0];   
    }

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 45*dataSource.count-1);
    self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95f alpha:1];
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NOSPersonSelectorCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PersonPopoverCell"];
}
```

This gets called 2 times:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PersonPopoverCell";
    NOSPersonSelectorCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15];

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    NSObject *dataObject = [dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    if ([dataObject isKindOfClass:[NOSUserInfo2 class]]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [(NOSUserInfo2 *)dataObject name];
        cell.pk = [(NOSUserInfo2 *)dataObject personPK];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [(NOSChild2 *)dataObject childName];
        cell.pk = [(NOSChild2 *)dataObject childPK];
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.18f alpha:1];

    //NSLog(@"%d", [S24SharedUserHandler selectedPk]);
    cell.checkmark.hidden=cell.pk!=[S24SharedUserHandler selectedPk];
    return cell;
}
```

And the result is that the tableview is empty.

New information 11 Jan 2017
The app works when testing on phone, but not on simulator. I still have no idea what is wrong and am really dissapointed in the downvotes I am still getting for asking this question. I would appreciate if somebody can explain why they think it is a bad question.

Apparently everything works on an iPhone 5. It does not work on iPhone 6 and up. Be advised that the iOS is still 10.2, for both the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 and 7 also have iOS 10.2

Since the only difference between working and not working is the device, not ios version, I am now leaning towards it being an UI bug that only occurs at certain sizes.

One other issue that arises is that my gesturerecognizer also only works on iPhone5 and not 6+

New info!

I can fix the problem by commenting the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` code. This now means that I need some other way to adjust the height of certain cells and that is the current problem. I still have no idea at all why uitableview behaves this way.

Comment: You need to explain your data model and post all of your table view data source methods.

Comment: What code do you need? I have nothing extraordinary going on and as I said the same code works on another platform. I have just not found anyone that have said that cellForRow has been called but not show anything

Comment: @Ostmeistro well your cellForRow code would be a good start. Also, possibly an explanation of the data model. Or maybe how you create the tableview and it's delegate/datasoruce

Comment: I have added some code for a simple part that is not working. Some code is pretty sensitive but hope that helps

Comment: @Ostmeistro is the cell definitely not nil after you dequeue it?

Comment: Yes, I can see all data is correct

Comment: @Ostmeistro that is not what I asked. If you put a breakpoint after dequeuing the cell is it nil or not? Also, are you certain that the tableview is added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, it is a cell full of correct data (again this code works on iOS6) It is not nil, it contains the name of the students among other things. The tableview is in the view hierarchy, I think it must be since it calls cellForRowAtIndex and gets a response with correct data. It stopped working when I changed target platform.

Comment: Does anyone care to explain why they downvote? Why am I getting anger for asking this it dosen't seem neccesary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this particular problem was that the method "heightForRowAtIndexPath" returns a double on iPhone 5 and long on iPhone 6, to be correct, one should use a defined datatype called "CGFloat"!

It was not easy to find this problem and I hope I can help someone else with this. Also thanks to anyone that tried to help!